# How to make show more link visible after two lines based on line-height in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

```
<div my-directive>
<div class="outerDiv">
<div class="innerDiv">
<p class="expandable">{{longText}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

directive.js

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) { console.log(element[o].getBoundingClientRect().height);
}
```

css:

```
.expandable{
height:40px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here whenever i run the code, i am always getting the height 40px. But I have to get the contents dynamically and i have to check height, if the content exceeds two lines, show More link should be visible. How Can i check this? kindly help

Comment: did you try `max-height:40px`?

Comment: yes. I have tried. If i use max-height. Iam getting 0 px. Problem is P class is present inside nested divs. I am using element=element[0].querySelectorAll('div.outerclass div.outerdiv div.innerdiv p.expandable) to get the expandable class. So even when i check this height, iam not able to get the offsetHeight or the actual height

Comment: Should also wrap in `$timeout()` to let content render first. Using `$timeout` will push to next digest

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yz3cTBSTVjggsdXNwHPQ?p=preview. I have created Plunker link. Can you please me where to provide timeout function to get teh actual height. When i tried adding timeout function, but its throwing error

Comment: I have updated plunker link with static data. For static text height is working. But when i make the text to dynamic with ng-repeat data, iam not able get actual height. Can you please help

Comment: I thought directive would be on `expandable` as you originally had in question. Then directive runs for each instance

Comment: Yes... Directive is in ng-repeat and for dynamic data, I am not able to get the actual height

Comment: but my point is directive is on wrong element. Create `ng-repeat` demo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116396/discussion-between-user1-and-charlietfl).

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3CMSOVNzN7cCsmDweW5Y?p=preview